# MySQL SET max_connections

Tags: mysql

¿Is there a way to change max_connections value in command line and keep it permanent?

I have used SET GLOBAL max_connections=xxx; but it always goes back to 100 (Default value) everytime I restart mysql service. I have read that if you change it from the my.ini file of mysql the changes will keep permanent, but it isn't a viable solution for my case.

Thanks in advice.

Comment: add it in start/restart scripts then.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I solved as Sebas said (found it easier). Perhaps I missed to write that I'm currently working on a java application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using php, you could run this query in your mysql connection wrapper if you have one.

For instance:

```
<?php
class CDBCnx {
    Public Function CDBCnx() {       

        /* implement your favorite pdo/mysqli driver to create your connection */
        /* the query function is imaginary: just run the query the way you wish */
        query("SET GLOBAL max_connections=xxx");
    }
}
?>
```

This way, everytime you instanciate a new connection in your script you will have the max connections the way you wish.

Comment: How could I missed it? Make a simple SQL Query in my application, and I'm actually working with Java but the mechanism is the same. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What I have found is, when I made my connections over the limit that system can handle it would reset to default value. For example default was 214 and I was trying to set more than 1000. Max my system could handle was 800. Just try to make sure you are not exceeding the limit.

Answer (score 0):

step 1 :  do it in console

```
set global max_connections=xxx;
```

Step 2 : Permanently edit it in /etc/my.cnf or my.ini (in windows) in the mysqld section so that the next restart wont rollback  it to the old value.

```
[mysqld] 
max_connections = xxx
```